# How to make UIButton on ViewController of TabBarController return user to last selected TabBarViewController (not current one) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a 5 tab TabBarController, with selectedIndex = 2 (3rd TabBarItem) being a full-screen camera embedded within a NavigationViewController with the Tab Bar and Navigation Bar hidden via `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true` and `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true` respectively.

I have a UIButton presented over the camera preview layer; currently, I'm implementing `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0` to navigate back to the 1st TabBarItem.

What I need:  How do I store the last selectedIndex (before selecting the Camera Tab) so that the UIButton returns to user to the last TabBarView before initializing the camera?

Keep in mind the camera is presented by TabBarItem (selectedIndex = 2) so its not presenting a modal view on top.

Logic Example:

VC1 > VC3 (Camera) > Select UIButton > VC1

VC2 > VC5 > VC3 (Camera) > Select UIButton > VC5

As an aside, I've implemented the following function in my TabBarController (subclassed with UITabBarControllerDelegate) to record the selectedIndex.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("The previous tab was index \(selectedIndex)") 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but if you are able to pass the *last* selectedIndex value to the Camera Tab, you could do several things with it - including storing it in a tag attribute of the button. Jut brainstorming....

Comment: I had a similar train of thought.  I saw some past comments on firing a notification and having the CameraViewControler "listen" and then implement.  If there was a way to leverage the listed tabBar function in my TabBarController, which is actively recording the preview tab, it seems I could just implement

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedIndex = [func tabBar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to save that index in `UserDefaults` in the `viewWillDisappear` of the five `ViewControllers` and retrieve it from when you click the button to navigate to that index

Comment: Thanks Alsh!  That set me in the right direction, I was able to streamline your suggestion to require less code.

Comment: Done, sorry first question on Stack Overlow. Learning community etiquette 

Comment: it's ok, you have the right to not vote up anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks to the suggestions I was able to make the process work.  Implementation code below:

In TabBarController

```
overrride fun tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("the previous tab was index \(selectedIndex)")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedIndex, forKey: "previousTab")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Within the UIButton on the CameraViewController

```
@IBAction func exitCamera(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let lastTab = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "previousTab") {
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = Int(lastTab)!
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.stopCaptureSession()
        }
    }
}
```

So far it works like a charm! :-)